# Playing coop with friends

Tags: dark-souls

I am thinking about purchasing Dark Souls to play with friends (primarily playing together and not alone).  I have read that a soapstone is needed to actually play co-op.  How long into the game can I get this?

Also, is it possible to play the entire campaign in co-op with a friend?  If you join a game, is progress saved for both the host and the joined players, or is only the host player saved (exp, items, story progress)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no, it is not possible to play the entire campaign in co-op. And this is for several reasons.

- First, as you mentioned, you cannot even do co-op until you after you
  beat the first (second if you count the tutorial) boss. Then you get
  your soapstone that lets you summon others.
- Second, you can only
  summon other players while you are human and staying human is not
  always easy. Especially if you are new to the game. Anytime you die
  you become hollow (non human) again and will have to use an item to
  become human and play co-op once again. To further complicate this
  point while you are human other players can enter your world and
  attack you. If they kill you you will go hollow. Some players that do
  this are very strong, and build themselves for the sol purpose of
  pvp.
- Third, there are simply some areas of the game that you are not
  allowed to play co-op in. These are also the areas of the game where
  pvp is not allowed.
- To address your other point. When playing coop
  you are summoned into your friends world (or they into yours). Any
  actions you preform will only affect that world. You will share exp
  (souls). But you will not find any items, only the host will. Furthermore, as a summoned friend you will not be able to heal yourself
  via flasks, but anytime your host heals you will also be healed. Also
  anytime you beat a boss you will be pushed back into your own worlds
  and will require re summoning.

I do not say this to discourage you from getting the game. It is one of my favorites and I highly recommend it. However if you are getting it solely for co-op purposes only you might consider looking elsewhere, or doing extra research to make sure this kind of co-op is for you.